# Arangodb Accessing database A Collection in database B

Tags: arangodb

I am trying to access one database collection in a different database. Is it possible in arangodb.

Regards,
Sajeev

Comment: Did you even do some research before you asked this?

Comment: I did some research yesterday, but did not find it. But today I got the answer from the manual.

Comment: Please note that commands, actions, scripts or AQL queries should never access multiple databases, even if they exist. The only intended and supported way in ArangoDB is to use one database at a time for a command, an action, a script or a query. Operations started in one database must not switch the database later and continue operating in another.

Comment: But it would be nice to have some facility to access multiple databases from AQL.

Answer (score 0):

No, its not possible.

ArangoDB strictly separates databases, so AQL doesn't know about databases in first place, its concept is below the database layer.

As we also discussed [in the github issue we actually don't intend to implement support for this](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/2046).